# probability that I toss two coins independently, and get two heads or two tails, assuming I discard all HT and TH outcomes.

Tags: probability, random-variables, random

Say I have two coins and I toss them independently, what is the probability that I get two heads or two tails, assuming I discard all cases where I get HT or TH.

So let coin one be Bernoulli(p) and coin two be Bernoulli(q), then is it just: $\frac{pq}{pq + (1-p)(1-q)}$ ?

This does not seem right since it is too simple. Again I am in a game where I discard all HT and TH outcomes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. If you continue to toss and discard TH and HT, then the probability is 1 that you will receive HH or TT. Can you clarify what you're trying to say here?

Comment: @bof fixed! Sorry about that!

Comment: the sample space is $\{HH,TT\}$, the outcomes are equally likely, so their probabilities are $0.5$ each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You have found a conditional probability.

If the first coin has probability $p$ of being heads and the  second has probability $q$ of being heads and they are independent,  then your expression $\dfrac{pq}{pq + (1-p)(1-q)}$ is the conditional probability that both are heads, given they are both head or both tails.

Conditional probability is as simple as $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B)=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) + \mathbb{P}(A^c \cap B)}$.